# When does the navigationDelegate in a WKWebView gets called if an error occurs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, webkit

Assume you are browsing the New York Times home page and you click a link to read an article *before* the page fully loads. The navigationDelegate get's called:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFailNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation withError:(NSError *)error;
```

The error is:

```
"The operation couldn’t be completed."
```

As we normally expect the new page (that contains the article) should start loading *after* the error is thrown. In fact, I have logged this and I observed that the article page starts loading *before* the error is thrown, at exactly the time you click the article's title.

What I'm trying to do is to get the article URL and the solution I came up with is to store the last URL that the webView starts loading and when the navigationDelegate get's called to report the error use the lastURL as the new page URL.

When this method get's called:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler;
```

Store the URL here:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSURL *lastURL;
```

What I'm afraid of is if the navigationDelegate get's called *after* a few more sub frames of the new web page are loaded, that will mess up the lastURL entirely. It will not have stored the article's true URL but some other URL that is part of the article.

So, when exactly does the navigationDelegate get's called to report the error? Can someone reassure me that my fears won't come true?

Comment: Have you get the anwser yet?